# Manipulate a dataframe (select specific variables) using a general IF condition for the whole dataframe

Tags: r

I'm trying to select specific set of variables using an if condition, on variables within the dataframe.

```
set.seed(123)
X1 <- sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)
X2 <- sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
X3 <- sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
X4 <- seq(1:10)
X5 <- seq(1:10)

df <- data.frame(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5)

df_result <- ifelse(all.equal(df$X4 , df$X5) , df[ , 1:2], df)
```

This code turns df_result into a list and not a dataframe.
What I'm trying to do, is if all of the values of X4 and X5 are exactly the same, then I want to keep first two columns, otherwise keep the dataframe as it is. It's specifically those two variables I want to keep using an instruction. I'm not trying to remove duplicated variables.
Is it possible to manipulate a dataframe this way? Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `if` would be more suitable as the condition with `all.equal` returns a single TRUE/FALSE and we are using this to select the first two columns or the entire dataset.

```
df_result <- if(all.equal(df$X4 , df$X5)) df[1:2] else df
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     select(if(all.equal(X4, X5)) 1:2 else everything())
```

---

With `ifelse`, the length of all the arguments should be the same - the logical expression returns a single TRUE, where as 'df[1:2]' is two column data.frame - length 2 and number of elements (nrow(df) * 2), no condition returns the full dataset (length - 5)